# Capture Screenshot of entire page with Selenium in IE9

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the `CaptureEntirePageScreenshot` working for IE9. I have read a lot of docs and wikis to get this working but nothing has worked for me so far.

So I thought I would use snapsie directly. So I downloaded the dll and registered it using these [instructions](http://snapsie.sourceforge.net/). I then used it directly:

```
selenium.GetEval(js_code + "this.browserbot.getUserWindow().Snapsie.saveSnapshot('C:\\pic\\test.png');");
```

However, I get the error:

> automation server can't create object

Any ideas?

I would appreciate any general help on getting snapsie.js to work. I am using the latest selenium server (2.9.0) on a Windows 7 machine with IE9 and FF4. I am using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using Snapsie, but the most simple way to get an Screenshot from an Internetexplorer is to use the InternetExplorerDriver itself:

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
// change this line if you want to use an different Browser / WebDriver Implementation
//driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
query.SendKeys("Cheese");
// TODO: wait
((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"screenIE.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: this doesn't look like its going to work with selenium. I can't just open another browser to another page.

Comment: I am sure it works with selenium (Selenium 2 / WebDriver), i just tried it. Put my code in a simple C# Console Application, reference the Selenium .Net dll's and start it.

Comment: I am not targeting just IE. I am using Selenium to open several browsers. So I can't use the above with Selenium as Selenium won't be driving the test case it will be the `InternetExplorerDriver`.

Comment: ok, than change the code slightly. Use an interface, and use whatever implementation of Selenum (Browser) you want. --> i changed the code of the answer to the more generic usage. (Beside from that i am wondering why you called your question "Capture Screenshot ... in IE9" if you want to use any browser!?)

Comment: Perfect thank you! It's going to be difficult to migrate to the web driver but it can do what I need it to do.